# Find the first "1" in zero array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array `"0000011111"`

I need to find the first occurrence of `"1"`.

How can I do that in efficient way  ?

my solution is:  (I think there is a better way)

```
$array = array(0,0,1,1,1);


for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    if($array[$i] == 1)
    {
        var_dump($i);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming nothing about the order of elements in the array, this is the most efficient solution already.

Comment: @sircodesalot: Binary search only works if the array is sorted, and for an array that small it wouldn't help anyway.

Comment: @sircodesalot I guess a binary search would apply if the elements in the array happen to be sorted? I didn't see anything in the question that suggested that.

Comment: @sircodesalot but what if he encounters an array like this: `00100000100000000` ?

Comment: What is the performance problem you're trying to solve? That code will run extremely fast even on an ancient processor given your sample data.

Comment: @user450_user Also make sure you consider the case where there are no 1s in the array. (Think about what you want to print/return in that case.)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is already as efficient as possible, but there's a [built-in method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) in PHP that will do this for you:

```
$array = array(0,0,1,1,1);

var_dump(array_search(1, $array)); // int(2)
```

Note that `array_search` will return the boolean `FALSE` in the case where there are no 1s in the array.

**EDIT**

I made the assumption that the original code is PHP just because it looked that way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since there is no necessity for any of the numbers to be `"1"` and since you are only going through the array once, this is the most efficient solution. Binary search or any such algorithm wont work as this array is quite obviously not sorted.
Sample inputs:

1. `0101101`
2. `1000101`
   In either case, binary search would not work.

Comment: This does not need to be italicized.

Comment: *I like my posts italicized.*

Comment: it's obvious that `0000011111` is not sorted.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj okay, so some other arrays that the OP didn't give us as examples are not sorted...

Comment: @SamIam Umm, when commenting on my post, please do not use @ sign as it pings my notifications twice. Also, I see your point now. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

If you can somehow convert the array efficiently to a number, It is possible to find the first 1 efficiently with log base 2.

```js
var number = 0b010000010;
console.log(Math.floor(Math.log2(number)))
```

**EDIT** The main reason for doing this is because there are hardware instructions for doing log base 2 that make it constant time.

Of course if you cannot store your array as a binary string, because it is too long or something like that, this solution is not for you.

Comment: Can you think of a way to convert the array to an integer that's faster than what the OP is doing?

Comment: why the downvote? If you can store your array as a binary string, this totally works, and has hardware support.

Comment: The first one should be in position 0, would it not? Or are you accounting on reversing the array?

Comment: I was assuming he wanted to know the highest order 1 since the code in the original post did so.

Comment: Not sure how relevant this answer is anyway, but yes, you'd have to flip the order of the input to get this to work. E.g. the position in the first 1 in "000010" would be `Math.floor(Math.log2(0b10000))`.

Comment: if we are talking about first left to right, then the code i have above is correct for littleendian binary representations.